# Grafana процессор в 100%

Tags: linux, grafana

Такая проблема - раз в сутки примерно сервер графаны уходит в 100% по процу, доступа из вне закрыты.
Примерно графиков 100 настроено. В логах нет ошибок, вообще не понятно почему. 
Может кто то сталкивался с таким?
Спасибо